# Why was the ExoMars Rover to use such as complex parachute system?

Tags: mars, parachute, exomars

American Mars landers use a single, supersonic main parachute. The European/ Russian ExoMars rover was to use a much more complex 4 parachute system consisting of a drogue, a main and a pilot for each of those.

The parachutes were the primary reason for the two year delay from 2020 to 2022. Why did they decide on this system over a more simple, single parachute?

Image for reference [(source)](https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Human_and_Robotic_Exploration/Exploration/ExoMars/ExoMars_parachute_progress):
[image]

Comment: Because a single, supersonic parachute is not "simple" - if not done right they have a tendency not to open.

Comment: A parachute system is needed that will work from supersonic down to very slow speed and from very low pressure to surface pressure. Deceleration should be neither too small nor too big.

Comment: @RAD6000 please source the image

Comment: @ErinAnne done, sorry I didn't do it firstly

Comment: This is not that complex. Orion has 11 parachutes that deploy in 4 phases.

Comment: @JörgWMittag for Mars it is. The combined mass of the Skycrane-Perseverance is much greater than the Kazachok-Rosalind mass. There’s got to be another reason it it’s going for 4 chutes.